# Width of widget

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

In PyGTK what is the easiest way to figure out the dimensions of a widget? I know that it is easy to do with the gtk.Window object, but I can't find in the reference manual any way to get dimensions for the other objects.

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for the [get_allocation](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--get-allocation) method:

> The get_allocation() method returns a
>   gtk.gdk.Rectangle containing the
>   bounds of the widget's allocation.

or [size_request](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--size-request):

> The size_request() method returns the
>   preferred size of a widget as a tuple
>   containing its required width and
>   height. This method is typically used
>   when implementing a gtk.Container
>   subclass to arrange the container's
>   child widgets and decide what size
>   allocations to give them with the
>   size_allocate() method. Obtaining a
>   size request requires that the widget
>   be associated with a screen, because
>   font information may be needed.
>
> Also remember that the size request is
>   not necessarily the size a widget will
>   actually be allocated.

The latter is what the widget would *like* to have as its size (given font information), the former what it's actually *given* by its container when it lays out the widgets.